# Heroku app served as HTTP with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, heroku, https

I have deployed a web application in Heroku using node.js but within the application I need to make a request to an HTTP endpoint that returns a JSON file. While making the request, I get the a Mixed content error. I understand this happens because my application has been served through HTTPS but the request is HTTP. How could I tell heroku to serve my application as HTTP or what should I do to make it HTTP? Will this solve the problem?

Comment: Is the HTTP endpoint under your control?

Comment: no, its a third party service

Comment: HTTPS is advantageous to the user. I'd first reach out to the third-party to see if it's also available in HTTPS. If not, I'd proxy the requests via your Heroku app to allow your users to continue using HTTPS on it.

Comment: how could I do that? I was making the request using AJAX initially

Comment: Make the request to an endpoint on your app, which uses cURL (or something similar) to server-side pass that request on to the real endpoint and return the results.